# Two Sliders in Gtk.Range or Gtk.Scale

Tags: gtk, vala

Is it possible to have two sliders in a single Gtk.Range or Gtk.Scale widget? I want to represent a value that has upper and lower bounds. It can be achieved with two slider but a slider having both bounds seems to me more intuitive.

If it is not possible can I implement this by extending either of them? I looked up the source code but it seems like slider object is added via private methods.

Edit: What I want is exactly like [this npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dual-range-slider)

Comment: Well, if I understand right then this function does what you need ==> https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/GBinding.html

Comment: @Michi I don't think that's what I am looking for. I added an example of what I want.

Answer (score 1):

No, you shouldn't use or subclass `Gtk.Scale` for this use case. Like you mentioned earlier, the drawing it uses is completely internal to the class, so you can't really re-use. But also in general, the API doesn't really match to what you specifically want, since it assumes a single-value. Even `Gtk.Range` still provides methods likes `range.get_value()`, so how would that work out in case of an upper and a lower bound? Ideally you just write your own widget, which supports the exact API you want.

Note: this should become easier to implement once GTK4 comes out, as each part of the scale will then be "just another widget". which you don't necessarily have to redraw each time.